# Table within table fouls up vertical alignment of neighboring cells!

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I nested a table inside of my table like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{1in}||p{5in}}
    \hline
    This should be on top. & \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lr}
                    Thing1 & Thing2 \\
                    Thing3 & Thing4 \\
                    Thing5 & Thing6 \\
                    Thing7 & Thing8 \\
                 \end{tabular} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

and it looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Pf1Ihn7.png]

but since `This should be on top` is in a `p` cell, shouldn't it stay up on top? How can it be made to look like this? :

[image]

Comment: Why don't you put that cell in a minipage with the `[t]` placement option?

Comment: The posted answer gives the answer, to see why: the two cells are p columns so align on the baseline of their top row. In the first cell their are two boxes from the linebroken paragraph so the baseline of the first is taken, the second cell just has a single line paragraph consisting of the nested table so the beaseline of the table is taken, which is its centre as `[c]` is default, so the top line of the left aligns with the centre of the table. If you use `[t]` the baseline of the table is that of its top row.

Comment: @YuppieNetworking a `minipage[t]` would not change anything (that is essentially the same as a tabular `p` column that is already being used).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, ok thank you for the clarification, I knew that the `p` resulted in a minipage but I wasn't sure if it was already with the `[t]` placement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
\begin{tabular}{p{1in}||p{5in}}
\hline
This should be on top. & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lr}
                Thing1 & Thing2 \\
                Thing3 & Thing4 \\
                Thing5 & Thing6 \\
                    Thing7 & Thing8 \\
             \end{tabular} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Note the extra `[t]` in there.